# Is this Android SQL statement vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is the `query()` method provided by `SQLiteDatabase` class safe to use without worrying about SQL injections?

```
db.query(TABLE,cols,COL_ID + " = '" + id + "' AND " + COL_FROM + " = '" + from + "'",null,null,null,null);
```

The `id` and `from` variables are completely unescaped.

Or is the following the only safe way to go?

```
"column=? OR column2=?", 
      new String[] {"value1", "value2"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the `query()` method provided by `SQLiteDatabase` class safe to use without worrying about SQL injections?

No.

`query()` is essentially just a wrapper for [`SQLiteQueryBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) and it constructs a raw SQL statement that gets executed as is.

> Or is the following the only safe way to go?

Not strictly speaking the *only*, but an easy and safe way, yes.

(Note that you switched `AND` to `OR`.)

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.